# php info doesn't show GD settings

Tags: php, macos, apache2, gd

I am running Apache2 on Mac OS X 10.5.8
I followed instructions for installing GD for Apache2 on Mac OS X 10.5.8 and restarted my Apache2

If I go to bash

```
bash-3.2$ php -m | grep gd
gd
```

So that means I have it installed but when I do

```
echo phpinfo();
```

I don't see any GD settings. How can I fix this?